# issues in working with android portrait mode with opencv

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera, face-detection

I know this is one of the most repeated questions, however, no working solution found anywhere, after putting so much of efforts.

This is really a killing issue though it might be a simple one for the experts.

I am working on **opencv Haar Cascade** classifiers.(Eg: Face Detection, Eye Pair Detection)

I have just taken the **face-detection sample** code from the **"OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk" - samples.**

This sample code is set in **Landscape** mode and everything is working **fine**.

However, i want to make make the classifiers work in **portrait** mode. I know the haar **classifiers** were **not made to work with portrait mode**.

As opencv uses "**CameraBridgeViewBase**", i d**on't have all controls** to play with the resolution of the camera and displaying the
images back on the screen.(preview)

Now, the moment i set the screen orientation as "**android:screenOrientation="portrait"**, the images is rotated **90deg clock** wise.

**What have i tried:**

**To preview the portrait image without rotation**: i modified the "**deliverAndDrawFrame**" in "CameraBridgeViewBase" by adding

```
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.preTranslate((canvas.getWidth() - mCacheBitmap.getWidth()) / 2,(canvas.getHeight() - mCacheBitmap.getHeight()) / 2);

            if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
                matrix.postRotate(90f,(canvas.getWidth()) / 2,(canvas.getHeight()) / 2);
            canvas.drawBitmap(mCacheBitmap, matrix, null);
```

**To make the classifier work with portrait mode:** 
I played with all kinds of permutation and combination of **transpose** and **flip** to rotate the grey scale image that i pass to detectmultiscale in "onCameraFrame".

**What is my issue?**

1. I am not able to get the images with native resolution which is higher than what i get at "onCameraFrame".
   **How to get the original or actual or native quality of the images upto the camera sensors capacity?**
2. **As i already put a lot efforts on making the classifier work with portrait mode without any luck, any kind of suggestions/sample codes/reference which are working,would help me a lot.**

Comment: Can anyone gives me a hand?

Comment: The devs are unwilling to help us, and there is an enormous amount of conflicting ideas of how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
  Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
  matrix.preTranslate((canvas.getWidth() - mCacheBitmap.getWidth()) / 2,(canvas.getHeight() - mCacheBitmap.getHeight()) / 2);
  matrix.postRotate(90f,(canvas.getWidth()) / 2,(canvas.getHeight()) / 2);
  float scale = (float) canvas.getWidth() / (float) mCacheBitmap.getHeight();
  matrix.postScale(scale, scale, canvas.getWidth()/2 , canvas.getHeight()/2 );
  canvas.drawBitmap(mCacheBitmap, matrix, new Paint());
```

This delivers portrait mode with CORRECT scale :D try it please. I'm using OpenCV 3.4 .